# VB.NET xml node

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have the following XML and I can't seem to select the appropriate nodelist.  I am using:

```
nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("/TaskOfArrayOfCorporationn0S_PdIRS/Result")
```

But this is not returning the corporation node.  XML is formatted as follows:

```
<TaskOfArrayOfCorporationn0S_PdIRS xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Threading.Tasks">
<Result xmlns:d2p1="Corporations">
    <d2p1:Corporation>
        <d2p1:AlternateAddress i:nil="true" /> 
        <d2p1:AlternateCity i:nil="true" />
        <d2p1:AlternateState i:nil="true" />
        <d2p1:AlternateZip i:nil="true" />
        <d2p1:BusinessName>GABRIEL’S COFFEE SHOP LLC</d2p1:BusinessName> 
        <d2p1:BusinessStatus>Active</d2p1:BusinessStatus> 
        <d2p1:Category>LLC</d2p1:Category>
        <d2p1:DateOfIncorporation>2018-05-18T00:00:00</d2p1:DateOfIncorporation>
        <d2p1:DissolutionDate i:nil="true" />
        <d2p1:Duration i:nil="true" />
        <d2p1:ExpirationDate>2019-05-31T00:00:00</d2p1:ExpirationDate> 
        <d2p1:ForeignBusinessName i:nil="true" />< 
        <d2p1:RegisteredAgentAddress>532 SILICA RD NW </d2p1:RegisteredAgentAddress> 
        <d2p1:RegisteredAgentCity>QUINCY</d2p1:RegisteredAgentCity> 
        <d2p1:RegisteredAgentName>VERONICA SOSA</d2p1:RegisteredAgentName> 
        <d2p1:RegisteredAgentState>WA</d2p1:RegisteredAgentState> 
        <d2p1:RegisteredAgentZip>98848 9466</d2p1:RegisteredAgentZip> 
        <d2p1:StateOfIncorporation>WASHINGTON</d2p1:StateOfIncorporation> 
        <d2p1:Type>LLC</d2p1:Type>
        <d2p1:TypeDescription>WA LIMITED LIABILITY COMPANY</d2p1:TypeDescription>
        <d2p1:Ubi>604288731</d2p1:Ubi>
    </d2p1:Corporation>
</Result>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get XML Node Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010974/get-xml-node-data)

Answer (score 0):

Try `XPathSelectElement`

```
nodelist = doc?.XPathSelectElement("/TaskOfArrayOfCorporationn0S_PdIRS/Result")

If nodelist Is Nothing Then
   'path was not found.
End If
```

`Nothing` will be returned if the path cannot be found.